# How to convert from radial / polar velocity to cartesian velocities

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Suppose I have the following coordinate system:

[image]

My input is:

- Radial length $\rho$
- Radial velocity $\dot{\rho}$ (constant velocity)
- Angle $\phi$, where $\tan(\phi) = \frac{y}{x}$

Desired output:

- x-velocity $\dot{x}$
- y-velocity $\dot{y}$

**How do I convert the radial velocity $\dot{\rho}$ to Cartesian velocities $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$?**

I've already computed $x$ and $y$, but I'm not sure if they're helpful:

$
\begin{align}
\sin \phi &= \frac{opp}{hyp} = \frac{y}{\rho}\\
y &= \rho \sin \phi \\
\end{align}
$

and

$
\begin{align}
\cos \phi &= \frac{adj}{hyp} = \frac{x}{\rho}\\
x &= \rho \cos \phi
\end{align}
$

Comment: Is $\phi$ constant?

Comment: Yes, $\phi$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is constant the conversion is straightforward, indeed we simply have that

- $\dot x=\frac{d}{dt}(\rho\cos \theta)=\dot \rho \cos \phi$
- $\dot y=\frac{d}{dt}(\rho\sin \theta)=\dot \rho \sin \phi$

Comment: Thank you. That's awesome.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 You are welcome! Bye